# Emulate Samsung Galaxy Tab

Tags: android, android-emulator, tablet

I would like to test my application with new Samsung Galaxy Tab tablet.

What parameter should I set in the emulator to emulate this device?

- What resolution and density should I set?
- How can I indicate that this is a large screen device?
- What hardware does this tablet support?
- What is the max heap size?
- Which Android version?

Comment: FYI, from the Android Developer Blog: "In the case of the Galaxy Tab, Samsung will be providing an add-on including a custom AVD and skin as an SDK add-on, to make your life easier;"

Answer (score 89, accepted):

**UPDATED:**
Matt provided a great link on [how to add emulators for all Samsung devices](http://developer.samsung.com/technical-doc/view.do?v=T000000095).

*OLD:*
To get the official Samsung Galaxy Tab emulator do the following:

1. Open the Android SDK and AVD Manager
2. Click on Available packages
3. Expand the Third party Add-ons. There you will see Samsung Electronics add-ons.
4. Once the add-on is installed create a new emulator.  Under Target you will see the new Samsung Tab settings, select that.

That's it!

Comment: Also, see this page for more information: http://innovator.samsungmobile.com/cms/cnts/knowledge.detail.view.do?platformId=1&cntsId=9445

Comment: I had trouble finding this until I selected "Sort by: Repository".

Comment: I can't find "Third party Add-ons" in the SDK Manager Revision 21.1 _ anyone knows where to get it please? under Tools > Manage Add-on Sites, there are now 2 tabs: Official Add-on and User Defined Sites. Maybe I should add it there but what's the url to use to have the Samsung Electronics add-on ?

Comment: I couldn't find the Add-on like Hubert mentioned too!! please help!!

Comment: Yah, fricken Google changed the SDK yet again, and those instructions no longer apply :(

Comment: You have to set them up manually now, Samsung now has instructions here for all of their devices: http://developer.samsung.com/technical-doc/view.do?v=T000000095

Comment: None of the links work.. Samsung, doing its best to stifle innovation again

Comment: URL is no longer available

Comment: Looks like this is the new site: https://developer.samsung.com/galaxy/emulator-skin/guide

Comment: Your link is broken

Comment: Evidentally Google does not want us use anything except their phones. Trying to for devs to buy their phones? I've bought 3. They all unexpectedly died. Lost most of my data because very little of it could synch to Google. And on the last one, the little that could was a bit older than I would like. And other ones I could not access because if device cannot be activated.. and after a short number of months Google DELETES it all. I'm so done with Google Phones. I liked them, When they worked. They never did follow through on reimbursement. This was several years ago. Other devs burned too!

Comment: @AustinMullins That's just a skin.

Answer (score 10):

You can't.

> "The Samsung Emulator has the same functionality as the Generic
>   Android Emulator, but varies with the size and appearance of the
>   device."

The problem with Samsung is that they don't use a generic android image, they have custom apps and they react in custom ways and do weird things you wouldn't expect and when you're trying to fix bugs that's what you want. You cannot get that. You need access to a physical device to get the right ecosystem to hunt down the bugs and map out which intents work and how they work on that device. And sometimes there are errors that only occur on Samsung devices because some of the core rendering code is different as well. I've had errors where all Android devices except Samsung would work flawlessly but the scheme itself could not work on Samsung and had to be scrapped. The only thing Samsung allows is skinning and that won't properly note the changes in the rendering pipeline or how the samsung ecosystem deals with intents.

You can make the device look similar, that's worthless. I don't care what it looks like, I care whether this bug still affects that particular model or whether the tweak to the intents I made rectified the issue and I can't learn that from a pretty picture as the border to the same device.

Comment: This is the correct answer. You can't. Not possible. Use a real device.

Comment: But how is it possible to find all real devices?

Comment: Buy some of them. Usually the Samsung ecosystem is pretty unique so you can use Google and Samsung and have a good mix.

Answer (score 5):

I found under website.

http://developer.samsung.com/android/tools-sdks/Samsung-GALAXY-Tab-Emulator

Extract zip file to add-ons under android sdk path.
then launch Android SDK Manager.
under "extras" folder
check "Android + Google APIs for GALAXY Tab, API 8, revision 1" item and install package.

That's all.

Comment: I followed the same steps but now in extras i am able to see "GALAXY TAB by Samsung.... so on" but it has red file broken icon on hover says Addon Failed to Load: Unable to find base platform with API Level '8'. Do you have any idea on how to fix this.

Comment: @HBK I know this is old, but I have the same problem, did you find the solution?

Comment: @216 No clue what I was working on then. Sorry, I couldn't help you out.

Comment: Your link is broken

Answer (score 4):

> What resolution and density should I set?

- 1024x600

> How can I indicate that this is large screen device?

- you can't really (not that i know of)

> What hardware does this tablet support?

- http://www.samsungmobile.co.uk/mobile-phones/samsung-galaxy-tab-specification

> What is max heap size?

- not sure

> Which Android version?

- 2.2

Hope that helps - check the spec page for all unanswered questions.

Comment: what about density? I heard that it has got not standard (high) density.

Comment: "In this context, the Samsung has another little surprise: If you do the arithmetic, its screen has 170 DPI, which is far from the densest among Android devices. Still, it declares itself as “hdpi” (and as having a “large” screen size). The reason is simple: It looks better that way." --- I have found this at google blog, but I do not know how to understand that. Is it 170 dpi or just standard hdpi?

Comment: If it has 170 DPI, that means it's closer to mdpi (160 DPI), not hdpi (240 DPI).

Comment: @ xil3 I know that, but pls read message from google blog. Should I set 170 dpi or 240 dpi in the emulator?

Comment: 170 is certainly false. The is only 120, 160, 240 and 320 available. Everything else has to to be rounded up or down.

Answer (score 4):

Go to this link ... https://github.com/bsodmike/android-avd-profiles-2016/blob/master/Samsung%20Galaxy%20Tab%20A%2010.1%20(2016).xml

Save as xml file in your computer. Go on Android Studio => Tools => AVD Manager => + Create Virtual Device => Import Hardware Profiles ... choose the saved file and the device will be available on the tablet's section.

Happy Android developments guys!!!

Answer (score 3):

If you are developing on Netbeans, you will not get the Third-Party add-ons.  You can download the Skins directly from Samsung here:
http://developer.samsung.com/android/tools-sdks

After download, unzip to ...\Android\android-sdk\add-ons[name of device]

Restart the Android SDK Manager, and the new device should be there under Extras.

It would be better to add the download site directly to the SDK...if anyone knows it, please post it.

Scott

Comment: That url goes to http://developer.samsung.com/technical-doc/list.do and is just a technical documentation list..

Comment: Man...crazy web developers have changed things again!  After a lot of searching, it looks like Samsung has removed all references to those emulator skins.  They want you to use their real device lab.  Makes sense for final testing, but would be nice to have a tuned emulator for early testing!

Answer (score -2):

I don't know if it is help.
Create an AVD for a tablet-type device:
Set the target to "Android 3.0" and the skin to "WXGA" (the default skin).
You can check this site.
http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/optimizing-for-3.0.html

Comment: Galaxy Tab have got 2.3 version of the system.

Comment: Galaxy Tab 2 have got Android 4.2.1 version