# How to create avd for samsung galaxy tab

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Emulate Samsung Galaxy Tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3745491/emulate-samsung-galaxy-tab)

I want to check my application on a samsung galaxy tab. Can anybody tell me how much resolution I need give to create the avd? And how to create an emulator like the samsung galaxy tab?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this out:

http://innovator.samsungmobile.com/galaxyTab.do

Is a Samsung's official Galaxy Tab AVD.

Answer (score 1):

You can actually download a Samsung component via AVD that contains a configuration for Galaxy Tabs.

Here are [precise instructions](http://innovator.samsungmobile.com/galaxyTab.do). I would recommend this over simply entering the resolution manually.

Comment: that url gave me an error

Answer (score 0):

Resolution is 1024×600! You can enter an exact resolution in the Android SDK and AVD Manager.