# How can I emulate HTC Desire or Samsung Galaxy

Tags: android, sdk, android-emulator, android-2.2-froyo

I'm using the android SDK just to test my mobile websites (not to develop own android apps).
How can I emulate different devices like Samsungs Galaxy S or HTC Desire or the Galaxy Tab?
I'm asking because those devices seems to have different screen/viewport-dimensions.

And how can I test newer Android versions (e.g. 3.0) for Smartphones? Every time I create a device with newer android versions than 2.2 I get a tablet device starting up.

Many Thanks
Konrad

Comment: FYI: 3.0 is developed for tablets, not smartphones. 2.3 should start up a smartphone device (can't remember it ever did otherwise here).

Comment: Oh ok. Didn't know that ... thouht 3.0 was for tablet TOO ... and not only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the Android simulator, you can create a custom device with a lot of different density.

To simulate devices:

[Android SDK and AVD Manager](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/devices/managing-avds.html)

For emulate galaxy tab:

[Emulate Samsung Galaxy Tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3745491/emulate-samsung-galaxy-tab/4473842#4473842)

Comment: Thank you ... But how did I know, what resolution to choose for the different phones? When WVGA800, QVGA, WQVGA432 ... looking for a simpler solution where I can select the phone ;-)

And is there a way to emulate real phone (with their default manufacture ROM installed) ?

Comment: There isn't a specific HTC, Samsung, etc. emulator like Galaxy Tab emulator. Personally, I think the best way is to get the phone deteails from web and create a new emulator. For example: Desire S  have a 3.7-inch 480 x 800 screen, Android 2.3 and 1 GB built in memory.

Comment: [This is the android screen support documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html), read the **How to Test Your Application on Multiple Screens** Chapter at the bottom of the page.