# How to make emulator for Galaxy Tab or Kindle Fire?

Tags: android, android-emulator, kindle-fire, galaxy-tab

If I go to specifications of tablets Galaxy Tab and Kindle Fire, I see that their resolution is 1024 x 600 pixels, 7.0 inches, and dpi is ~170 ppi. If I create emulator based on these info (1024x600, 170dpi) and test it via tools like `ScreenInfo` app, I see that they are registered as `Large MDPI`.

Real devices are registered as `Large HDPI`. This means that these specifications do not represent the real state of a real device.

Why is this different? How to make an emulator for these tablets which will really reflect the real devices?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3745491/emulate-samsung-galaxy-tab

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why is this different?

Because the device manufacturers in question chose to categorize their devices that way.

> How to make an emulator for these tablets which will really reflect the real devices?

As the comment indicated, you can get [a Tab emulator image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3745491/emulate-samsung-galaxy-tab) that is what Samsung recommends that you use.

As far as the Kindle Fire, you follow [Amazon's instructions](https://developer.amazon.com/help/faq.html#KindleFire) to get the emulator that they recommend. You will not get a precise match, because Amazon's firmware works differently than the 2.3 stock firmware (which is not fully set up for tablets).

Comment: do you have any idea why google statistics on screen sizes and densities state that there are 0 (zero) devices with Large HDPI resolution when both mentioned tablets are categorized as Large HDPI?

Comment: @sandalone: The Kindle Fire does not use Google Play, and hence will not be reflected in statistics based on Google Play. With respect to the original Tab 7", perhaps it did not sell enough to get 0.1% of the market share. You would have to ask Google how they calculate that.