# How to open the Android SDK and AVD Manager together

Tags: android, sdk, android-virtual-device

I am trying to install the Samsung GALAXY Tab Emulator for Eclipse but I can't find the  "Android SDK ***and*** AVD Manager". I can only find them individually:

[image]

I can't see any options on either the AVD or the SDK manager that lets me install the Emulator. On the Samsung developer website it tells me I need to use the **Android SDK and AVD Manager**:

[image]

Where can I find this program?

Comment: what you want to do actually??

Comment: @Prag's "I am trying to install the Samsung GALAXY Tab Emulator for Eclipse"

Comment: you want to create new AVD?

Comment: @Prag's Yes, using the Samsung Galaxy Tab Emulator download from the Samsung Developer website

Comment: if you want to create new AVD then goto AVD MANAGER and Create New AVD with specified screens and devices...

Comment: OR could you provide me link of your device sdk

Comment: see my answer.. that may help you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think You are following this Link :

[Using-Samsung-Emulators-for-Android-Application-Development](http://developer.samsung.com/android/technical-docs/Using-Samsung-Emulators-for-Android-Application-Development)

this **tutorial is so OLD** so There is some updates in it you have to follow..

1. Download **SAMSUNG TAB EMULATOR**
2. After Downloading the skin extract the zip file and copy it in the path Android SDK > Platforms > android-x > skins. In android-x (x is the platform version number)
3. In Eclipse IDE go to Window > **Android Virtual Device Manager**.
4. To Create New Android Virtual Device **Click On New** And in the **Device** field **Select Device with Specified Resolution** And in the **Target** Field **select Android API level** (Android API level must be same where the skin has been copied) from the drop down list available.
5. Then **select** the Built-in option in **Skin options** available. And in the built-in option drop down box find the skin added in the platform and select.
6. Now click on **OK** button to add the new skin. (**NOTE :** please chose all related information according to fields)

and **Your AVD has been created succesfully**..

Hope This Helps...

Comment: This is what I've actually just done myself 20 mins ago. but thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

I don't think, you really need to launch them concurrently to install Samsung Emulator, but if you really need it you can do it from command line. Just go to android-sdk/tools folder and run:

**./android sdk** 
for Android SDK manager

**./android avd**
for Android AVD manager

it will be probably **android.exe** on Windows, but should work the same way.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below cited answer from Kim Ki Won, I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3745491/emulate-samsung-galaxy-tab):

"I found under website.

http://developer.samsung.com/android/tools-sdks/Samsung-GALAXY-Tab-Emulator

Extract zip file to add-ons under android sdk path. then launch Android SDK Manager. under "extras" folder check "Android + Google APIs for GALAXY Tab, API 8, revision 1" item and install package.

That's all."