# Add Third Party Emulators for Android Studio 2.0

Tags: android, android-studio, android-virtual-device

I am trying to emulate a `Samsung Galaxy Tab E` in the AVD on Mac. However, most of the documentation is old [see this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3745491/emulate-samsung-galaxy-tab) and doesn't apply to studio 2.0.

*How do I add or emulate other devices in Android Studio 2.0 that are NOT apart of the pre-installed templates?*

Comment: Use the "New Hardware Profile" or "Import Hardware Profiles" buttons on the first page of the "Create Virtual Device" wizard to define something matching your desired specifications.

Answer (score 1):

I understand the question as, why isn't there an easier way to use the "import hardware profiles" button to simply bring in a preconfigured profile off manufacturer sites?  Haven't found one yet...

For emulator skins, which will give you the device's layout and look, but not the hardware specs, Samsung has a great tool http://developer.samsung.com/galaxy/emulator-skin